# Editing the path on k8s cluster with a helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to edit my path like I would normally on a unix system.  Let's say I want to append the path /opt/test/ to my path environment variable.  How do I go about doing this with a helm chart on kubernetes?  I am also using openshift if that helps.  I have tried within the values.yaml file under config:

```
config:
   PATH: "/opt/test/:$PATH"
```

This does not seem to work as the helm install breaks down.  I am new to k8s and any help would be thoroughly appreciated.

Comment: how is the config referenced in the helm chart? Setting the path as an environment variable like this will usually not work, as the variable replacement occurs only in the context of a shell. It is better to do this in the dockerfile of the image. If the processes in the container will use a login shell, then another way could be to populate `export PATH=/opt/test/:$PATH` in ~/.bashrc file in an init container.

Comment: thank you very much.  Do you possibly have a docker file I could reference to modify the path variables?